# how to remove user from sharepoint Farm

Tags: active-directory, user-profile-property, spuser, active-directory-import

I want to remove a user from SharePoint from all Web applications in SharePoint Farm. Like the user has never existed! is ti possible? 
I see there many users that don't exists in AD anymore.  But I still see them into SharePoint.

other thing: how will Sp Manage this situation?  When it will find a Document created by a User that will disappear from SharePoint ?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things.

- if you have the User Profile Service enabled then setup a filer to exclude the disable /deleted account from importing.[Creating User Profile Synchronization Exclusion Filters using the userAccountControl attribute](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2011/02/22/323.aspx)
- If you want to remove the user from  sharepoint then i recommend to use this powershell script.

**Funcations:**

```
 Function RemoveUser($LoginName,$SiteUrl) 
    { 
        #Get site 
        $Site = Get-SPSite | where {$_.url -eq $SiteUrl} 
        If($Site) 
        { 
            $Web = $Site.openweb() 
            Try 
            { 
                #Get user 
                $user = $web.SiteUsers  | where {$_.UserLogin -like "*$LoginName"} 
                #Remove user 
                if($user) 
                { 
                    $web.SiteUsers.Remove($user) 
                    write-host "Remove user $LoginName from site '$SiteUrl' successfully." 
                } 
                Else 
                { 
                    write-Warning "User $LoginName not found on site '$SiteUrl'." 
                } 
            } 
            Catch 
            { 
                Write-Error $_ 
            } 



    } 
}
```

then run the command like this:

```
 RemoveuserFromwebapplication.ps1  -LoginName "user1" -SiteUrl "http://win-chu4c2rckti:8080/sites/project"
```

[How to remove certain user from a SharePoint site (PowerShell)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-remove-users-from-a-e4d9f1d5)

- When a user removed from SharePoint and all the documents or items created or modified by it, assign to system account.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a user in SharePoint 2010, Navigate to the site collection as a Site Collection Administrator.
Click on Site actions >> Site permissions.
Select the user you want to delete, and click on Actions >> “Delete user from Site collection”

Hope This Works,
Peter